# Understanding gyrometer readings using the Unity3D API

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

I am building a game that at one point relies on raw gyrometer readings. I am getting the readings using the following code (I'm using C#):

```
void Start () {
    Input.gyrometer.enabled = true;
}

void Update() {
    _guiText = Input.gyrometer.attitude.eulerAngles.ToString();
}
```

I'm displaying the values on screen in the `OnGUI()` method. As I'm using Unity I'm using a right-handed coordinate system and I've noticed that the Y value from the gyrometer corresponds to the X rotation in Unity.

The problem is that these values jump around massively. For example I can be holding the device at X:90° and rotate slowly through the Y Axis; after a certain point (around the 270° mark) the X will suddenly flip 180°. It means however, that if I start the app while the device is at 270° in the Y the X reading will be completely unusable. The same effect happens in the Z axis.

I have managed to get round this on iOS devices by resetting the gyro readings using the following snippet: `Input.gyro.enabled = false;` followed by `Input.gyro.enabled = true;` I use this to get an accurate reading of the device's absolute rotation and then I use rotational changes to get any other device movement. This doesn't work on Android however.

Has anyone come across this before? If so how did you get round it or is a bug that cannot be resolved?

Comment: Euler angles are always unreliable (as @fafase stated in his answer). Use quaternions themselves instead. I would even refrain from Quaternion.Angle. To get an idea how dangerous Euler angles are, take a look at the Wikipedia article about [Gimbal Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)

Comment: Hi @Kay. I'm aware of Gimbal Lock I am converting the quaternion to a euler, editing the euler and then converting back to quaternion. Will this still cause issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are reading a conversion of Quaternion. Euler angles in Unity are just a friendly way to get a V3 representation of something that is hard to grasp. It is recommended not to affect eulerAngles directly as well as using them for reference. Instead, think of flat device as one rotation then start getting the angle between default rotation and current rotation and use that value to define your actions.

You can use Quaternion.Angle for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks. i am getting rid of any references to eulers in my code and seeing if it resolved it.

Comment: It is going to make things a bit harder to debug and understand since you no more work in 3D but in 4D. That is until you realise you do not need to fully understand what is going on, just to understand how to use it and what to expect. It does not mean you should not read about quaternions and learn but the topic is fairly deep and advanced.

Comment: I can already use quaternions, just got caught up on the whole gimbal lock thing because as you said eulers are a lot simpler. Just to clarify, if I want to rotate the gyro by -90 around the X the code would be: `Quaternion rotation = Input.gyro.attitude * new Quaternion(1, 0, 0, -(Mathf.PI / 2.0f));`?

Comment: Ok this is where you are going to hate me, to rotate a quaternion by a euler value you use...Quaternion.Euler. The reason is that 90 degrees does not mean anything in Quaternion system, it is all about trig and division of it. Your rotation could be currentRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-90f,0f,0f);

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not getting anywhere, when I rotate the device around just the X or the Y I'm still getting rotation movement in all axis. I cannot adjust the Quaternion to get the desired rotation. I've achieved this using the iOS SDK and core movement framework fine. I don't know why unity has to make life difficult.

Comment: This is the problem of quaternion. If you move one axis, you get the fourth one being updated as well. If you move on x and then on z or y, all 4 values are being modified. This is what quaternions are all about. It is no more the accumulation of three rotations with three different possible result depending on order of movement, quaternion is a rotation (orientation) by itself. An easy way is to have landmark rotations and compare your current rotation with those. You cannot rely on euler since -90 is also 270 while there is only one rotation for a set of values.

Comment: I now have a workable solution. I'm multiplying the inverse of the default rotation by the current attitude to get the relative rotation. Thank you so much for your help. I'm sure I'll get more used to quaternions as time goes on.

Comment: @RASS Can you post a more complete "Answer" to this question? I feel like there is a lot of discussion, and some natural language expressions of math, but no hard math / no hard solution provided.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know. The question was about the difference between a Quaternion rotation and it's euler rotation which has been answered by fafase